# Send Image Bitmap to a Django server

Tags: android, python, django, bitmap

I am developing my first android app. I need to send the bitmap to a django server. I have no clue on how to do that. I have searched it on the StackOverflow. Some have suggested sending it as a JSON object or a bytearray. I am really confused. What's the best practise and the most efficient and fastest way of doing it and how to implement it on android? Do I need to convert it to Base64 perhaps? Also if I choose one of these methods, how to configure django to read them?

Comment: does your server have an api?  if so, what does the api require for an image upload

Comment: Uhm.. What kind of API?

Comment: how do you talk to your server..

Comment: Does the expects you to send an image? what's the name of the view? what are the parameters and media types it accept. That information is vital when uploading data.

Comment: Why dont u send it directly as post data to the any url-view  which may  handle posted data in django server?